# sonarscanner interrupted in Plugin [l10nzh] defines 'l10nen' as base plugin

Tags: sonarscanner

sonarscanner interrupted in Plugin [l10nzh] defines 'l10nen' as base plugin. This metadata can be removed from manifest of l10n plugins since version 5.2. there is no error but no progress, why? other ubuntu system is ok.

tell me how resolve it.